# The render's colors are flat and too plasticish next to the 3D viewport, how to fix this?

Tags: lighting, color

so I'm struggling for a while to figure out how to have the same color/light management in my render as they are in my 3D shading viewport [here is what I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f52Y7.png)
[and here what I have in my render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmqZa.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: you can just drag & drop images into the question or CTRL-C/-V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

When you're anticipating the render to look like the viewport, consider what means of illumination is being used.  Are there lights in the scene?  Perhaps the viewport is using an HDRI but a different one is being used in the World Environment...?

The checkboxes seen above in the viewport shading settings might also affect the difference between viewport appearance and rendered appearance.  Both checked should use whatever settings the scene has, while un-checking them will override the scene settings.

Comment: Thanks, it appears that I had different hdri and my rendering one had bad light disposition for my scene

Comment: Excellent.  I'm glad it worked out! Care to check it as an answer?  ; )